# Hyper-V Manager: right-clicking on local or remote VM crashes MMC snap-in

Tags: windows, hyper-v

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise SP1 machine that I log into and use to manage virtual machines running on multiple Hyper-V servers on our domain. Sometimes, when I right-click on a local or remote VM, the Hyper-V Manager will crash and display the following error message:

[image: Screenshot of Hyper-V Manager showing the error message "MMC has detected an error in a snap-in and will unload it."]

If I use the Actions menu on the lower right, it works just fine, but for some reason right-clicking causes MMC to stop working. Is there any way to fix this issue? Here are the full details of the error message.

```
Description:
  Stopped working

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: mmc.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 6.1.7600.16385
  Problem Signature 03: 4a5bc808
  Problem Signature 04: Microsoft.Virtualization.Client
  Problem Signature 05: 6.1.0.0
  Problem Signature 06: 4ce7c9e3
  Problem Signature 07: 342
  Problem Signature 08: 1f
  Problem Signature 09: System.OverflowException
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.274.10
  Locale ID:    1033

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Also this stack trace:

```
FX:{922180d7-b74e-45f6-8c74-4b560cc100a5}

Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

  at Microsoft.ManagementConsole.Internal.SnapInMessagePumpProxy.OnThreadException(Object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.OnThreadException(Exception t)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProcException(Exception e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr wndProc, IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ListView.WndProc(Message& m)
   at Microsoft.Virtualization.Client.Controls.EnhancedListView.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looks to be an issue with [HyperV snapin crashing when running on a second monitor](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverhyperv/thread/b4a46edb-3e49-4680-ada2-e06262197e52/)

> You aren't going to believe this. We figured out what it was finally
>   and it was fairly complicated :)
>
> We found a bug with the Hyper-V MMC snap in that is very repeatable.
>   With Win2k8R2, hook up a machine to an external monitor (I was doing
>   this on a laptop). Then, move the MMC (server manager in this case)
>   the external monitor. Try to right-click on any VM in Hyper-V and it
>   will crash. As soon as you move it back to the main monitor it works
>   fine again.
>
> Go figure!

I can confirm these results on my system, which has 2 GPUs with 4 monitors total (See below). If i use HyperV manager on the primary display or lower half of monitors 3 and 4 then everything works, but as soon as I move it above the vertical height of the primary display and try to right click it will crash. I have been working with Microsoft Support to resolve the issue (SR number 112110960192323 ) and will follow up if a hotfix or workaround is found.

[image]

Comment: ............wow

Comment: ***WHAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAT?*** I.... this.... Even for MS this one is impressively bad. I suppose the workaround while you're waiting for a patch is `Drag the HyperV manager so it's in the lower half of the virtual display area before you right click on things`?

Comment: Note: This is only above the top of Screen 1, anywhere below works just fine.

Comment: Seems to be a somewhat common issue, where the position of the context menu is calculated using the the primary display's dimensions instead of the full dimensions from multiple displays. I have seen similar errors in Java applications, where the context menu is displayed on a different display or causes the application to crash. Just one of those end cases that doesn't get tested very often.

Comment: `if (monitors.moreThanOne){explode()}`

Comment: `Oh my various Gods!`  Outstanding find.

Answer (score 8):

It seems that a rogue Windows Update is responsible for this. You can uninstall it by running `wusa.exe /uninstall /kb:2686831`, the reboot, then reinstall the update via automatic update and reboot again. This fix is outlined in [this TechNet forum post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winservermanager/thread/170a9d15-d9f1-4aff-a74d-365f993669c2).

If that doesn't work, I'd try uninstalling RSAT and reinstalling it.

Comment: Tried it, still have the same issue :-( Also since this is a 2008 R2 Server I cannot remove RSAT without removing the HyperV role.

Comment: I just saw the note on your bounty that reads: `Any help on how to prevent this crash or where to report it to Microsoft?` - Assuming you have a support contract with Microsoft (which I hope you do if you virtualize with Hyper-V), you can [open a ticket here](https://support.microsoft.com/oas/default.aspx?gprid=1044&st=1&wfxredirect=1&sd=gn). If you don't have a contract, there is a pay-per-incident option as well. I've had good luck opening tickets and **not** paying if it's an "unpublished but known" issue, but obviously YMMV there.

Comment: We have support incidents through our MSDN accounts. I submitted a ticket and will see if it is a known issue or if they can create a hotfix. Thanks for you assistance!

Answer (score 1):

A couple of basic suggestions/questions.

- Updates? - You list out that it has SP1 but not whether you're current on everything else.
- Hardware? - What are you running it on and do you have the latest drivers/firmware?
- Is it production? - Is there anything running on the server in question?
- Reinstall the role. - Have you tried that?

Comment: All current windows updates are installed, and this issue has occurred on multiple systems (HP Z400 workstation, Dell servers, IBM Servers). Not production environment, but has occurred on both dedicated and shared hardware. Seem intermittent, occurs repeatedly some days, then starts working without any noticeable changes.

Comment: sounds like a bad update, but I would first remove and install the role again; hopefully you do not have any local VM's on that machine